# Making a piece of text non-breaking?

Tags: html, css, nowrap

say I have a piece of text like this

> Hello I am some text Hello I am some
>   text Hello I am some text Hello I am
>   some text **I do not wish to be broken
>   on new lines**

Consider the above paragraph. I want for the bolded part to not be broken across a new line if possible. As in, I want it to break if it would require a scrollbar or something, but not break if it is possible to insert a page-break before or after that piece of text so that it can fit on one line.

How is this possible? I have tried things like `page-break-inside` and such, but it doesn't seem to do anything in firefox.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use the [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) property:

```
Hello I am some text Hello I am some text Hello I am some text
Hello I am some text <span class="nobr">I do not wish to be
broken on new lines</span>
```

with:

```
span.nobr { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Comment: I considered that, but I figured it would cause an unnecessary scroll bar, but it doesn't. Thanks!

Comment: @Earlz ...so you considered the solution yet you asked before even trying it? **That's a big no-no here!** :P

Comment: @xDaizu Stackoverflow 6 years ago was a lot different than now heh

Comment: The white-space property will not cause a horz-scroll bar if there are other points to break the line, e.g. two pieces of text and one or both cannot be broken. Very useful.

Answer (score 12):

Adding this for completeness:

If you do not want to use CSS, you could use `<nobr>text with space</nobr>` - reference [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/nobr)

**For pure text blocks**, i believe not-anymore-depricated html formatting tags like `<i>`, `<b>`, `<nobr>` and alike are valid for use.
**For content relating to the site structure** use `<em>`, `<strong>` and `<span class="">`.

Comment: Btw. it is not and can not be depricated. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28532140/1644202

Comment: `nobr` is not standard and `white-space` should be used instead according to https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Comment: But white spaces don't prevent non-textual splitting (like phonetic notation, for instance), so <nobr> is a savior =]

Answer (score 7):

bootstrap 4 has a class="text-nowrap"

more here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow