# Making a piece of text non-breaking in a language that does not use spaces

Tags: html, css

Very similar to this question:

[Making a piece of text non-breaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359443/making-a-piece-of-text-non-breaking)

However, I am doing this on Chinese and there are no spaces used.  I want to make sure so a book title or other phrases are not broken up and have orphan words.  How do I do this?

Note: I tried using `<nobr>` but that isn't behaving properly.  Sample code and screen shot of the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
  <td style="width: 25em;">《1字字字字》,《2字字字字》,《3字字字字》,《4字字字字》,<nobr>《5字字字字》</nobr>,<nobr>《6字字字字》</nobr>,<nobr>《7字字字字》</nobr>,<nobr>《8字字字字》</nobr>,<nobr>《9字字字字》</nobr>,《10字字字字》</td>
</table>
<br><br>
<table border=1>
  <td style="width: 25em;">《1字字字字》,《2字字字字》,《3字字字字》,《4字字字字》,《5字字字字》,《6字字字字》,《7字字字字》,《8字字字字》,《9字字字字》,《10字字字字》</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The `<nobr>` is ignoring the possibility of a line break in the commas, so it is treating element 5 and on as a single line, pushing the cell past the width I have setup.

Additional Note:  I just did a quick test of using `span.nobr { white-space: nowrap; }`.  It does the exact same thing as `<nobr>`, so I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: What is the rule that you want to implement for where breaks can and cannot occur? You want to break on the `,` character, and nowhere else?

Comment: I want all words inside the `《》` brackets to be non-breaking.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...

```
<td style="width: 25em;"><nobr>《1字字字字》,《2字字字字》,《3字字字字》,《4字字字字</nobr>》,《5字字字字》,《6字字字字》,《7字字字字》,《8字字字字》,《9字字字字》,《10字字字字》</td>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g2gpoajz/)

Adding a class and using jquery, something like this?

```
<td class="nobr" style="width: 25em;">《1字字字字》,《2字字字字》,《3字字字字》,《4字字字》,《5字字字字》,《6字字字字》,《7字字字字》,《8字字字字》,《9字字字字》,《10字字字字》</td>
```

jquery..

```
$(function(){
$(".nobr").text(function () {
    var addNobr=$(this).text().replace(/\《/g, '<nobr>《').replace(/\》/g, '</nobr>》');
    $(this).html(addNobr);
});
```

});

Result...

[image]

[New Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g2gpoajz/93/)

Comment: It does not seem too useful to hard-wire the `<nobr>` tags into the input. How would you generalize this solution?

Comment: This involves me manually calculating where it works and I have to add the tag manually, which is just super tedious.  I have a whole page of written material like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [<wbr>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) (Word Break) tag to indicate where one word ends and the next begins, telling the browser that a break could go there. If your page is encoded in Unicode you can also use the [U+200B](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x200B/index.html) character (which acts like a space but doesn't print anything) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this? it works for me.

CSS:

```
td div.nobr { display:inline-block; }
```

HTML:

```
<table border=1>
    <td style="width: 25em;">
        <div class="nobr">«1????»,«2????»,«3????»,«4????»,</div>
        <div class="nobr">«5????»</div>,
        <div class="nobr">«6????»</div>,
        <div class="nobr">«7????»</div>,
        <div class="nobr">«8????»</div>,
        <div class="nobr">«9????»</div>,
        <div class="nobr">«10????»</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

You basically put each one of your character's group into a div, and you set a display:inline-block; property to all the div.