# Prevent breaking of content in Yii2 GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

This is column display:

```
'columns' => [ 
    [ 
        'label' => 'Attribute Value-Pair',
        'value' => function ($model) {                                
            return $model['attribute_group_name'] . ':' . $model['attribute_name'];                
        },
    ],
],
```

The output is:

> Size:Yellow
>
> Length:30

But I want the output to be: `Size: Yellow, Length: 30` in single row.

Comment: If i print $model is shows the result as 
Array
(
    [attribute_group_name] => Size
    [attribute_name] => Yellow
)
Array
(
    [attribute_group_name] => Length
    [attribute_name] => 30
)

Comment: If i return this 
return $model['attribute_group_name'] . ':' . $model['attribute_name'];
It shows Size:Yellow in first row and Length:30 in second row.
But i want the result as  Size:Yellow,Length:30 in single a row. How is it possible ?

Comment: What dataprovider are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's layout problem. You can use `white-space: nowrap` CSS rule for preventing breaking words on separate line:

```
'format' => 'raw',
'value' => function ($model) {   
    $content = "$model->attribute_group_name $model->attribute_name";                             
    return Html::tag('span', $content, ['class' => 'no-br']) ;
},
```

And add to CSS:

```
span.nobr { white-space: nowrap; }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359443/making-a-piece-of-text-non-breaking) for example.

Alternatively if it's acceptable you can increase minimal width of this column:

```
'value' => function ($model) {   
    return "$model->attribute_group_name $model->attribute_name";                             
},
'options' => ['class' => 'class-name-for-this-specific-column'],
```

And in CSS:

```
.class-name-for-this-specific-column { min-width: 150px; }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `'format' => 'raw'` when your function outputs raw html.

Comment: @Beowulfenator Good remark, thanks. Corrected the answer.

Comment: It doesn't solve the original problem, unfortunately. In the question, `Size: Yellow` and `Length: 30` appear in two distinct rows of the grid view, so the break is between these entries, not between `Size` and `Yellow`. The only solution is to reorganize the original data provider.

Answer (score 0):

[@arogachev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626940/428543) would work if the data is in the same parent element e.g a table cell. However, it looks like your content is in different "models" and therefore different rows of the same table since the gridview prints each element in its own row.

This requires a custom solution to loop through the models array and extract each attribute-value pair individually e.g.

```
$attribute_values = [];
foreach ($models as $model) {
    $attribute_values[] = $model['attribute_group_name'] . ': ' . $model['attribute_name'];
}
echo implode(", ", $attribute_values);
```

You no longer need the gridview if you do this.

Comment: Unless there are some more columns, in which case he should keep the grid, reorganize the data provider, and run your `foreach` function in the cell callback.